# Declaring value with class property on input field

Tags: php

again! I've already made an

```
echo "<input type='number' name='total' value='$employee->totalSalary($raise,$pay)' readonly='readonly'>";.
```

But it says:

> Notice: Undefined property: Employee::$totalSalary in C:\xampp\htdocs\salary.php on line

Though, I have this property:

```
$id1 = $_POST["id"];
$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$lname = $_POST["lname"];
$pay = $_POST["salary"];
$raise = $_POST["raise"];

$employee = new Employee($id1,$fname,$lname,$pay);
```

I have this function to get my total annual salary:

```
function totalSalary($raise,$salary){
        $raisePerc = $raise / 100;
        $annual = $salary * 12; 
        $annualTotal = ($annual * $raisePerc) + $annual;
        return $annualTotal;
    }
```

I want to display the total annual salary on the number/text field. Thank you for answering. :)

Comment: It seems `totalSalary` is not an instance method of the Employee class, but `$employee->totalSalary($raise,$pay)` assumes so...

Comment: @marekful But if only echo that `$employee->totalSalary($raise,$pay)` (without the input field), it displays the total annual salary.

Answer (score 0):

the function arnt in the class so u can't use $employee->totalSalary

```
class Employee {
//set up other function ...


public function totalSalary($raise,$salary){
        $raisePerc = $raise / 100;
        $annual = $salary * 12; 
        $annualTotal = ($annual * $raisePerc) + $annual;
        return $annualTotal;
    }
}
```

Comment: It never shows the result inside the input field. I still get the same error.

Comment: try $employee->totalSalary($employee->raise,$employee->pay) if it still no work i have no idee then @AndianBandibas
up load you class Employee content will be helpful

Comment: Fixed it. I just declare `$sal = $employee->totalSalary($raise,$pay)`, and I replace the input value to `value='$sal'`.It works, though. Thank you so much. :D

Comment: @AndianBandibas nice :D just a notice next time when u put a variable try ->value=' ".$employee->totalSalary($raise,$pay)." ' ; it could avoid the maximent error when php turn var to string :9